# How to make mobile menu transition "backwards"?

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I'm trying to animate a mobile menu, so when clicking on it the three stripes should turn into an 'X', and when closing the menu it should revert back to three stripes. The animation to an 'X' works brilliant but when closing it just jumps back to being three stripes instead of smoothly transitioning back to it. This is because I'm removing the `x` class completely of course, but I can't figure out how I would actually transition "backwards"..

Here's my code so far:

HTML:

```
<button id="nav-toggle">
  <span class="toggle-pin"></span>
  <span class="toggle-pin"></span>
  <span class="toggle-pin"></span>
</button>
```

CSS (sass):

```
#nav-toggle {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9000;
  float: right;
  margin: 15px 15px 0 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;

  @include respondFrom(widescreen) {
    display: none;
  }

  .toggle-pin {
    width: 34px;
    height: 4px;
    background: palette();
    display: block;
    margin: 5px 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }

  &.x {

    .toggle-pin {
      margin: 11px 0;
    }

    .toggle-pin:nth-child(1) {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
      transform: rotate(45deg);
      -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .4s;
      transition: transform .4s;
    }

    .toggle-pin:nth-child(2) {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transition: opacity .3s;
      transition: opacity .3s;
    }

    .toggle-pin:nth-child(3) {
      margin-top: -30px;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
      -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .4s;
      transition: transform .4s;
    }
  }
}
```

The toggle script:

```
$navToggle.on('click', function() {

  if ($navToggle.hasClass('x')) {
    $navToggle.removeClass('x');
  }
  else {
    $navToggle.addClass('x');
  }
});
```

Comment: try to apply the transition to the nav-toggle element itself, not when `.x` is applied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define transitions by default:

## SCSS

```
#nav-toggle {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9000;
  float: right;
  margin: 15px 15px 0 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  cursor: pointer;

  @include respondFrom(widescreen) {
    display: none;
  }

  .toggle-pin {
    width: 34px;
    height: 4px;
    background: red;
    display: block;
    margin: 5px 0;
    border-radius: 5px;

    &:nth-child(1) {
      -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .4s;
      transition: transform .4s;
    }
    &:nth-child(2) {
      -webkit-transition: opacity .3s;
      transition: opacity .3s;
    }
    &:nth-child(3) {
      -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .4s;
      transition: transform .4s;
    }
  }

  &.x {
    .toggle-pin {
      margin: 11px 0;

      &:nth-child(1) {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
        transform: rotate(45deg);
      }

      &:nth-child(2) {
        opacity: 0;
      }

      &:nth-child(3) {
        margin-top: -30px;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        transform: rotate(-45deg);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> http://jsfiddle.net/vinzcelavi/d7uawp67/

Comment: Works, even though it doesn't look stunning but oh well :P